# jQuery post works on load, but not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I first implemented the following snippet to show a "hi" alert and do a jQuery post at "document ready". This first step worked fine. I then added a couple of lines to execute the block only on-click of a  tag. 
Now the "hi" alert works as expected (only after I click on the link), however the post returns an 'error, the post didn't work' and doesn't complete as expected. To reiterate, if I remove the 2 lines flagged with /***/ below, the code works just fine (immediately after the page loads). Any ideas why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.postlink').click(function() {    /*** post works if I remove this line ***/
    alert("hi");
    jQuery.post("http://myurl", 
            {registration_id: 'device1', command: 'MESSAGE', message: 'Hello', longMessage: ''},
       function(data) {
         alert("ok");
       })
       .error(function() {
        alert("error, the post didn't work");
        });
    });                                   /*** and this line ***/
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `jQuery.post` to `$.post` ?

Comment: Yes. Started with the short-form, but later used the fully qualified name to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `event.preventDefault()`;

```
<a href="#" class="postlink"></a>

$('a.postlink').click(function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
  // ...
})
```

Comment: That does it! Would love to know what the cause of the problem was, and why this solves it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sachin you are welcome, "If this method is called, the default action of the `event` will not be triggered." you can read more about preventDefault here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: This helped me, too!  In my case, I had an input box next to an input button.  jquery .click() worked for keypress on the box, but the button did not perform correctly.  You saved me from posting a question!